# How can I use the oracle REGEXP_SUBSTR to extract specific json values?

Tags: json, regex, oracle, oracle11g, regexp-substr

I have some columns in my Oracle database that contains json and to extract it's data in a query, I use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`.

In the following example, `value` is a column in the table `DOSSIER` that contains json. The regex extract the value of the property `client.reference` in that json

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '"client"(.*?)"reference":"([^"]+)"', 1, 1, NULL, 2) FROM DOSSIER;
```

So if the json looks like this :

```
[...],
"client": {
  "someproperty":"123",
  "someobject": {
    [...]
  },
  "reference":"ABCD",
  "someotherproperty":"456"
},
[...]
```

The SQL query will return `ABDC`.

My problem is that some json have multiple instance of "client", for example :

```
[...],
"contract": {
  "client":"Name of the client",
  "supplier": {
    "reference":"EFGH"
  }
},
[...],
"client": {
  "someproperty":"123",
  "someobject": {
    [...]
  },
  "reference":"ABCD",
  "someotherproperty":"456"
},
[...]
```

You get the issue, now the SQL query will return `EFGH`, which is the supplier's reference.

How can I make sure that "reference" is contained in a json object "client" ?

EDIT : I'm on Oracle 11g so I can't use the JSON API and I would like to avoid using third-party package

Comment: You should use Oracle's JSON API rather than pure regex.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yeah I forgot to add this to the question : I'm on Oracle 11g so no json API available unfortunately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using Oracle 12c or later then you should **NOT** use regular expressions and should use Oracle's JSON functions.

If you have the table and data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value CLOB CHECK ( value IS JSON ) );

INSERT INTO table_name (
  value
) VALUES (
  '{
  "contract": {
    "client":"Name of the client",
      "supplier": {
        "reference":"EFGH"
    }
  },
  "client": {
    "someproperty":"123",
    "someobject": {},
    "reference":"ABCD",
    "someotherproperty":"456"
  }
}'
);
```

Then you can use the query:

```sql
SELECT JSON_VALUE( value, '$.client.reference' ) AS reference
FROM   table_name;
```

Which outputs:

> | REFERENCE |
> | --- |
> | ABCD |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4499cd2006c0b64d403e466b61eceb60)*

---

If you are using Oracle 11 or earlier then you could use the third-party PLJSON package to parse JSON in PL/SQL. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65071745/65071994#65071994).

---

Or enable Java within the database and then use `CREATE JAVA` (or the `loadjava` utility) to add a Java class that can parse JSON to the database and then wrap it in an Oracle function and use that.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, unfortunately I'm using Oracle 11g, so first option isn't possible. Second option could be neat but my client won't install 3rd party package on his server so I'm stuck on this end too. I might use their scripts to find a way of doing what I want though

Comment: @Natty Maybe you could enable Java in the database and use a Java class to do the parsing? Or you can suggest to the client that they upgrade the database? (Trying to do it with regular expressions or other string functions is not going to work).

Comment: The database upgrade is a work in progress on their infrastructure (to be fair, it's been a work in progress for over a year now...), which is why they don't want to use 3rd party for "only a few months". Never heard of java code used in an Oracle function, I'll check how that works for sure !

Comment: @Natty I've previously done a few answers with examples; you can search StackOverflow for [user:1509264 \[oracle\] CREATE JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1509264+%5Boracle%5D+CREATE+JAVA) which will give a range of answers from the complex example which [unzips archives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59250531/1509264) to the simple [hello world](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60600349/1509264).

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue recently. If "reference" is a property that is only present inside "client" object, this will solve:

```
SELECT reference FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(
            DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(
                value,
                4000
            ),
            '"reference":"(.+?)"',
            1, 1, 'c', 1) reference
    FROM DOSSIER
) WHERE reference IS NOT null;
```

You can also try to adapt the regex to your need.

Edit:

In my case, column type is CLOB and that's why I use DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR function there. You can remove this function and pass column directly in REGEXP_SUBSTR.